# How do you find the index in R

Tags: r, vector, indexing

```
x <- 100:120
x[x > 105]
```

Find the index values of x>109 without any function

Comment: what do you mean by "without any function?" `>` is a function

Comment: I guess `x[x > 105] - 99` is an answer but obviously `-` is a function as well. If the student was taught, that functions are invoced using `()` than this kind of question would not be stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `which(x>109)`?

```
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```